# AzCopy - Unattended login

Tags: linux, azure, azcopy

Under Linux, I would like to know if there is a way to login using [*azcopy*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-and-install-azcopy) utility without going to the browser and enter the key its provide when *azcopy login* command is executed?
Is there a way to do it unattended and store the credentials in a file?
I would like to use *azcopy* utility in Shell Scripts to automate files download/upload from an ADLS2 storage container.
I would like to just provide the ADLS2 *Account Name* and *Shared Key* instead if all the other things like Client-Id, Client-Secret, Tenant-Id, etc.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service principal (app id and secret or certificate) to authenticate against Azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-login

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: Thanks Julian, 
But that is what I want to avoid. I don't want to use a service principal (and register the App in the AD). All I want to use is the Account Name and the Shared Key (Not even SAS keys)